# mockableAndroidJar FAILED

Tags: android-studio, gradle

```
:mylibrary:mockableAndroidJar FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task :`mylibrary:mockableAndroidJar`.

  > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$FileCreatorException: java.lang.NullPointerException
- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

`BUILD FAILED in 4s
 52 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 50 up-to-date
 23:20:03: Task execution finished 'makeJar'`

.

Comment: post full logcat output

Answer (score 1):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

//file: build.gradle(Project: your-project)
//fix mockableAndroidJar FAILED  
//start
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    tasks.each { task ->
        if (task.name == 'mockableAndroidJar') {
            task.enabled = false
        }
    }
}
//end
```

}